# Is the method didUpdateHeading called when app in background?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Is the method `didUpdateHeading`     called when     app is in background and registered for location updates?

Answer (score 1):

Heading updates will be delivered, if you have turned on location updates as well. For example you can do it like this:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
return YES;
```

Of course, this will incredible increase the power consumption. Therefore, you may turn down the location manager's distanceFilter and accuracy like this:

```
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 3000;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 3000;
```

This will make the power consumption better, since you only want the heading updates to be delivered.

I also tried to use startMonitoringForSignificantLocationChanges, but it did not work when the app is in background.

edit: don't forget to set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to NO. This will prevent you from stop working after about 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

To get location updates running on background (iOS 8.0+),

1. set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`  on info.plist
2. set `self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;`
3. set the background modes as shown

[image]

and then start updating. Sample code below:

```
self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is registered to use location services on background and `startUpdatingHeading` is called then YES

Comment: that method is called when I'm in the app, and I registered to use location services on background, but it doesn't work when I leave the app.

Comment: You need to call the method from the `locationManager:didUpdateLocation:fromLocation`. That is the only method that gets called when the app is in the `bg`.

Comment: So that means, I cannot get Heading everytime it's changed, right?